# ios app crashes with ACFoundation,error "AsyncInvoker ... DoInvoke.. asyncclosure" when i connect call for meeting with third peson

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, queue, webrtc

I am stuck and unable to comprehend the errors.
I have two views ChatViewController and other is VideoViewController.
ChatViewController has a table which shows lists of contacts.
When I click a button "Call", I should move to other view called VideoViewController.

VideoViewController has a UIview. However at runtime, I add subviews to it to render videos. When i stop rendering video, i remove my subview from its parent.

```
 localView.removeFromSuperview()
        remoteView.removeFromSuperview()
```

Then i want to dismiss this VideoViewController and move back to ChatViewController.

```
  dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in
```

}

It gives error while going back to ChatViewController.
Here is the output:

```
Thread 1Queue : com.apple.main-thread (serial)
Thread 13Queue : com.apple.root.default-qos (concurrent)
Thread 16Queue : com.apple.avfoundation.videodataoutput.bufferqueue     (serial)


  #0  0x0000000100311bf4 in rtc::AsyncInvoker::DoInvoke(rtc::Thread*,     rtc::scoped_refptr<rtc::AsyncClosure> const&, unsigned int) ()
#1  0x000000010021d5cc in void rtc::AsyncInvoker::AsyncInvoke<void, rtc::MethodFunctor1<cricket::WebRtcVideoCapturer, void (cricket::WebRtcVideoCapturer::*)(webrtc::VideoFrame), void, webrtc::VideoFrame> >(rtc::Thread*, rtc::MethodFunctor1<cricket::WebRtcVideoCapturer, void (cricket::WebRtcVideoCapturer::*)(webrtc::VideoFrame), void, webrtc::VideoFrame> const&, unsigned int) ()
#2  0x000000010021d15c in cricket::WebRtcVideoCapturer::OnIncomingCapturedFrame(int, webrtc::VideoFrame const&) ()
#3  0x00000001003e8b50 in webrtc::videocapturemodule::VideoCaptureImpl::DeliverCapturedFrame(webrtc::VideoFrame&) ()
#4  0x00000001003e8f0c in webrtc::videocapturemodule::VideoCaptureImpl::IncomingFrame(unsigned char*, unsigned long, webrtc::VideoCaptureCapability const&, long long) ()                                                                           #5  0x00000001003ec310 in -[RTCVideoCaptureIosObjC captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] ()
    #6  0x00000001847438e4 in -[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput _handleRemoteQueueOperation:] ()
    #7  0x0000000184743754 in __47-[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput _updateRemoteQueue:]_block_invoke ()
    #8  0x00000001866f57b0 in     __FigRemoteOperationReceiverCreateMessageReceiver_block_invoke ()
    #9  0x000000018670dcb4 in   __FigRemoteQueueReceiverSetHandler_block_invoke2 ()
    #10 0x000000010146cf94 in _dispatch_client_callout ()
    #11 0x0000000101484848 in _dispatch_source_latch_and_call ()
    #12 0x000000010146f1c0 in _dispatch_source_invoke ()
    #13 0x0000000101478384 in _dispatch_queue_drain ()
    #14 0x00000001014702c4 in _dispatch_queue_invoke ()
    #15 0x000000010147a5d4 in _dispatch_root_queue_drain ()
    #16 0x000000010147c248 in _dispatch_worker_thread3 ()
    #17 0x00000001983b522c in _pthread_wqthread ()
```

Please advise.thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please post your code or provide other details that would help us answer your question?

Comment: @jkdev sure. I have editted and added more information. Thanks

Comment: Are you using WebRTC?

Comment: @thefredelement yes i am using webRTC

Comment: @Sumaira remove the video tracks from being rendered before removing the view from the superview.